# Raspberry-pi 3B+ stopped working

Tags: pi-3b+

So last night everything worked fine. But when I turned on my rasp-pi this morning, it worked for a bit, then suddenly stopped working and only the red pwr led stays on while the green doesn't do anything. I inserted the SD card into my other Raspberry-pi, a Raspberry-pi 0 to be exact, and it worked fine. Please help.

Comment: The possibilities appear to be broken power supply or broken PI.  Only you can tell.

Comment: Try pluging your SD card into another pi3 or 3b+. You can test if it's the pi that broke, or the card

Comment: Please follow the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) and tell us, what step fails.